# Vue.js 3: emit an event is causing an error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to emit an event from a child component to its parent. I have read the [guide at vuejs.org](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#event-arguments) and thought that I had got the syntax correct. My child component (AxisLabel.vue) has

```
<script setup>
  ....
  const emit = defineEmits(['removeLetter', 'submitLetter'])
  const props = defineProps({
    stat: Object,
    index: Number,
    segments: Number
  })
  const point = computed(() =>
  {
    try {
      return valueToPoint(props.stat.value - 10, props.index, props.segments, true)
    }
    catch {
      return valueToPoint(0, 0, 9, true)
    }
  })
  function click() {
    if (props.stat.chosen) {
        props.stat.chosen = false;
        emit('removeLetter',props.stat.label)
    }
    else {
        props.stat.chosen = true;
        emit('submitLetter',props.stat.label)
    }
  }
  ....
</script>

<template>
    <text @click="click" :class=changeColour() class="prevent-select"
        :x="point.x" :y="point.y">{{stat.label}}
    </text>
</template>
```

and in the parent (app.vue) I have:

```
<script setup>
import AxisLabel from './components/AxisLabel.vue'
const tryingWord = ref('word')

function addToWord(letter) {
  tryingWord.value = tryingWord.value + letter
}
function removeFromWord(letter) {
  // ....todo....
 
}
</script>

<template>

  <svg width="300" height="300">
    <PolyGraph :stats="stats"></PolyGraph>
  </svg>
  <text class="prevent-select" rows="1" cols="9">
        {{tryingWord}}
  </text>

  <AxisLabel @submit-letter = "addToWord"/>
  <AxisLabel @remove-letter = "removeFromWord"/>
 
</template>
```

When I run this I get

> [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function
> at <AxisLabel onSubmitLetter=fn >  at

followed by an 'undefined' error (see below). This happens as soon as the app is started, i.e. without the click event being fired.

If I remove the event listener definitions from app.vue, the error doesn't occur.

[later]
I have now seen that, *without* the event listener defined, the `<text>` element of AxisLabel is called exacly 9 times (as it should be) - it's called from another component:

```
<axis-label
  v-for="(stat, index) in stats"
  :stat="stat"
  :index="index"
  :segments="stats.length-1">
```

and 'stats' has 9 members. But when I add back the event listeners, this  element attempts to get created a *tenth* time, with invalid parameters, causing the crash - the Chrome debugger indicates that 'props' is undefined in here :

```
<text @click="click" :class=changeColour() class="prevent-select"
    :x="point.x" :y="point.y">{{stat.label}}
</text>
```

'props' is used to calculate the position of the text, but adding the try/catch where it is used hasn't helped.

I need to see a *working* example of emitting an event in vue - vuejs.org doesn't seem to provide one.

Comment: By any chance, could this be the issue? :class=changeColour()
I don't think that class binding can be a function as you have written it?

Comment: The changeColour() function works OK, whether or not the emit and listener definitons are present. But I did try removing that binding and the error still occurs.

Comment: try `:class="changeColour"`

Answer (score 2):

There is an error inside your event handler function. I'm not sure, if this is the problem, but it might be.

```js
const tryingWord = ref('word')

function addToWord(letter) {
  // when working with refs, you need to use the .value property
  tryingWord.value = tryingWord.value + letter
}
```

Also, you should never mutate data, that is passed from the props as you do here:

```js
function click() {
  if (props.stat.chosen) {
    // this mutates the props
    props.stat.chosen = false;
    emit('removeLetter',props.stat.label)
  }
  else {
    // this mutates the props
    props.stat.chosen = true;
    emit('submitLetter',props.stat.label)
  }
}
```

you will find an explanation about the one way data flow in the [vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow).

### Update

As mentioned in the comments, the `AxisLabel` component does not receive any props which will lead to errors when accessing the props inside the `<script setup>`.

```
// the following line will throw an error
// because props.stat === undefined
if (props.stat.chosen) {
  // ...
}
```

You could either define a default property that is used when no property is passed or check the prop for undefined before using it.

Comment: Thanks. For your first point, I have already seen that error and corrected it in my code but forgot to update my question, sorry. I will do that now. Your second point could be the problem, I will look into that and try to learn more (Unless you can suggest a correction!)

Comment: A correction would be to much to think of, as I don’t know your context here. I think is an architectural problem rather and needs some more rethinking ;).

Comment: Also even if I don’t know what the `changeColour()` function is doing, I guess you can do the same thing with a computed property for the classes. I hope, the function is not performing any side effects which could lead to loops

Comment: Another thing is, that you don’t pass any props to the `AxisLabel` component which will lead to errors when you try to access for instance `props.stat.chosen` where `props.stat` will be `undefined`.

Comment: plenty for me to think about. I'm finished for today, hope I can sort it tomorrow....

Comment: My code is based on the example at  (https://vuejs.org/examples/#svg) , and that reads props in the same way in AxisLabel.vue. I agree that maybe I should not _change_ props here, so have corrected that but still getting same issue

Comment: Yes, i see. But you need to pass the `stat` to the `AxisLabel`  so that the prop is not undefined. Which is also done in the example.

Comment: I had passed `stat`, see the first few lines of my code. Anyway, the posted issue now solved, nothing to do with props, see my answer,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

```
<template>
  <svg width="300" height="300">
    <PolyGraph :stats="stats"></PolyGraph>
  </svg>
  <text class="prevent-select" rows="1" cols="9">
        {{tryingWord}}
  </text>

  <AxisLabel @submit-letter = "addToWord"/>
  <AxisLabel @remove-letter = "removeFromWord"/>
</template>
```

In fact there are 2 mistakes: Firstly, there are 2 calls to Axislabel and there should be just one:

`<AxisLabel @submit-letter = "addToWord" @remove-letter = "removeFromWord"/>`

Secondly, since Axislabel is a child of PolyGraph, I needed to propogate the events up through there to reach `App.vue`, i.e. these event handlers should be defined in `PolyGraph.vue`, not in `App.vue`